# Creating a categorical probability distribution based on scores

Tags: probability-distributions

I am looking for a method to create a categorical distribution from a set of possible options with an associated known score.

Example:
In a game where there are 4 options each rewarding the following a scores
Option 1: 1000 points
Option 2: 675 points
Option 3: 2 points
Option 4: 230 points

I want to create a categorical probability distribution where the likelihood of an option to be chosen is proportional to how good it is.
That is, option 1 should have the highest probability and option 3 should have the lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given example:

- $P(1)=\frac{1000}{1000+675+2+230}$
- $P(2)=\frac{ 675}{1000+675+2+230}$
- $P(3)=\frac{   2}{1000+675+2+230}$
- $P(4)=\frac{ 230}{1000+675+2+230}$

Note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4}P(n)=\frac{1000+675+2+230}{1000+675+2+230}=1$.

Comment: Looks kind of obvious now but that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @user1417861: You're welcome :)